# Google play game has stopped after update score to leaderboard

Tags: android, google-play, leaderboard

When I update my score to the leaderboard, and then I open the leaderboard, Google play game has stopped. Can anyone help me with this?

I update the score with this code:

```
Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(myclient, 
                    getString(R.string.number_guesses_leaderboard),  
                    HighScore);
```

I use this to open the leaderboard:

```
startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(
                myclient,getString(R.string.number_guesses_leaderboard)), 
                    0);
```

Click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPeeo.png) to see the Logcat.

Comment: Have you debugged your code? Where is that null value coming from? You didn't give us much to work with

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? It seems that I ran into the same problem. My post is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37099493/android-games-leaderboard-broken-while-testing